# sys.databases return different result when queried from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I need to collect all databases from stored procedure.

When I execute this code in SSMS, I get all databases available:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.databases;
```

However if I wrap this into stored procedure, I get only `master`, `tempdb` and current database:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ListDatabases
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
SELECT * FROM sys.databases;
GO

EXEC dbo.ListDatabases;
GO
```

This started to happen since SQL 2017 but worked fine on previous versions of MS SQL Server.

I would expect to get the same result when the procedure is executed under the same user account as the single statement. The account executing both queries is member of `sysadmin` server role.

Comment: Add `SELECT SYSTEM_USER, ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` inside the SP and check if the user is changing.

Comment: @MartinSmith I can see this behavior running the same version (`Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)`) on Windows and Linux

Comment: @EzLo the user is the same - `sa`

Comment: I can reproduce this, but only with a database that uses partial containment, and logging in with a user account from that database. Are you using containment, by any chance?

Comment: @JeroenMostert no, containment is not in use in my scenario. In both environments (Windows and Linux) the user is either `sa` or a Windows account that is member of `sysadmin` server role.

Comment: Well, unless you can give us a repro (complete with `CREATE DATABASE`/`CREATE USER`/`CREATE LOGIN` statements, preferably on a new, bare installation that's sure to have nothing like DDL/server triggers) this is going to be hard to troubleshoot. All anyone can say is that this is definitely not normal, out of the box behavior for SQL Server 2017. If necessary, double check with "stupid" things like `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` that you're looking in the right places.

Comment: Here's full repro:

`CREATE DATABASE SysDatabasesTest;
GO

USE SysDatabasesTest;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ListDatabases
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM sys.databases;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.ListDatabases;
GO
`

This returns only `master`, `tempdb` and `SysDatabasesTest` databases as output on my environment.

Comment: OK, be sure to [edit] that into your question, because you are *crucially* missing the `EXECUTE AS OWNER` clause -- that makes all the difference.

Comment: Using `EXECUTE AS OWNER` does not have any impact on the result. It's the same w/o `EXECUTE AS OWNER`

Comment: No, the problem *is* `EXECUTE AS OWNER`. On my installation, a procedure that uses this does not give back other databases; a procedure that does not use this does. In both cases I'm using integrated authentication, which may make a difference as opposed to SQL authentication.

Comment: I know and it was the first thing I've tried - remove `EXECUTE AS OWNER`. The result is always the same.

Comment: OK - I've missed I was having `EXECUTE AS OWNER` on procedure that was calling the problematic one. 
Many thanks for pointing me to solution @JeroenMostert

Comment: OK, then the world at least makes sense again. Although neither `sys.databases` nor `EXECUTE AS` document why restricting server-level metadata should be a logical consequence, I can imagine the implementation working that way. Turning on cross-database ownership chaining has no effect on this, but you may want to [read up on packaging permissions](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) in ways that avoid using `EXECUTE AS OWNER`, which may or may not offer a viable alternative for what you're doing.